# O que é esse <Buffer> na leitura de arquivos no NODEJS?

Tags: node.js

Estou aprendendo um pouco de `NodeJS`. A última coisa que aprendi foi ler um arquivo.

A questão que me deixou com dúvida é a seguinte. Quando utilizo a função `readFile` com o segundo parâmetro sendo `utf8`, a leitura do arquivo ocorre de forma esperada (do mesmo jeito que ocorre no PHP, linguagem de onde venho).

Exemplo:

```
var fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('files/text.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

Porém, quando não passo o argumento indicando que a leitura será como `utf8`, as coisas mudam:

```
fs.readFile('files/text.txt', function (err, data)
{
    console.log(data)
});
```

Saída:

```
<Buffer 4c 6f 72 65 6d 20 69 70 73 75 6d 20 64 6f 6c 6f 72 20 73 69 74 20 61 6d 65 74 2c 20 63 6f 6e 73 65 63 74 65 74 75 72 20 61 64 69 70 69 73 69 63 69 6e 67 ...>
```

Qual é o significado desse `<Buffer>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse buffer não é mais do que o ficheiro lido em formato "RAW". Se usares o `.toString()` ele é convertido em algo que dá para ler.

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('files/text.txt', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Respondendo a grosso modo. Este `<buffer ...>` corresponde aos dados binários alocados em memoria, memoria esta fora do heap V8.

**Buffer** no NodeJS:

*Buffer* é a instancia de uma classe no NodeJS. Cada *buffer* é alocado na memoria, como dito acima. O *Buffer* é como um Array de inteiros porem não é redimensionável. Possui métodos específicos para trabalhar com dados binários. Seus valores, que representam os *bytes* na memoria, possuem um limite de `0` á `255` **(2^8 - 1)**.

Referência: [How to Use Buffers in Node.js](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/advanced/buffers/how-to-use-buffers)

Answer (score 0):

O Buffer é o seu arquivo não parseado no formato hexadecimal.
Você pode pegar a sua resposta e parsear de formar simples. Segue um exemplo:

```
fs.readFile('files/text.txt', function (err, data) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
});
```